# Tunneling HTTP traffic from a particular host/port

Tags: firewall, proxy, http, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to figure out how to access from my development machine (`Devel`) to a third party web service (`www.domain.com`) which I am not allowed to directly contact using my office IP address.

Here's a basic diagram (i'm not allowed to post images...):
http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/%5BDevel%5D-%5BA%5D,%20%5BA%5D-%5BB%5D,%20%5BB%5D-%5Bwww.domain.com%5D

The only machine allowed to access that service is `B` (production server) but I do neither can directly access it from my development machine (`Devel`).

So in order to access the web service I have to ssh into `A`, and then from `A` to `B` to access `www.domain.com`

Is there any way of tunneling traffic from `B` to `A` and then back to my development machine so I can directly access www.domain.com without having to ssh into every box?

---

`Devel`: My development machine.
`A`, `B`: Linux servers. I own root access on both.
`B`: Production server
`www.domain.com`: Third party HTTP API production server uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. I do not do this on a regular basis, so when I need to I look up my bookmark on this, which is [here](http://www.linuxhorizon.ro/ssh-tunnel.html). Rather than to quote the article, just follow the very simple examples. They should be easy to set up for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: However you may want to first of all work with the networks and sysadmin teams to figure out why they have put in place this block so that you're not violating any policies which you're not meant to be breaking.

Comment: Ok, tried it and it actually worked, but HTTP request headers were wrong and apache returned a forbidden response. So I guess I need to find another approach.

@DaveG, there's no sysadmin teams here... and I already asked for a VPN account or whatever and they provided nothing. Or office has no static IP address so there's no way of doing things right.